# Excel macro only executing to ~60th row, then failing while making get requests

Tags: html, excel, vba, get

I modified code I found online to be able to find a ClassName on an HTML page and returns its text when doing a Google search. I need to do this for about 10,000 companies but when testing it with only 100 rows it works and then stops around ~60th row. After that I am unable to get any results and found the only way to resolve it is by waiting about an hour and then executing it again. I tested this on another computer and had the same results and issue. It doesn't have to do with what is in the ~60th row because I use a different set of 100 companies each test. Even changing the loop to i = 2 to 101 still causes it to have the same problem.

Col A would have a company name such as: "Buchart Horn"

Col B returns "Architect in Baltimore, Maryland"

Col C would be blank (that's fine)

Col D returns "Baltimore, Maryland - Buchart Horn: Engineers, Architects and Planners"

I'm very new to VBA so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
'References enabled: 
'Microsoft Internet Controls, Microsoft HTML Object Library

Sub GoogleSearch()
Dim URL As String
Dim objHTTP As Object
Dim htmlDoc As HTMLDocument

Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")

Dim objResults1 As Object
Dim objResults2 As Object
Dim objResults3 As Object

On Error Resume Next

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 2 To lastRow

URL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(I, 1)

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

With objHTTP
.Open "GET", URL, False
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
.send
htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText

End With

Set objResults1 = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("YhemCb")
Set objResults2 = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("wwUB2c kno-fb-ctx")
Set objResults3 = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("LC20lb")

Cells(I, 2) = objResults1(0).innerText
Cells(I, 3) = objResults2(0).innerText
Cells(I, 4) = objResults3(0).innerText

Next

Set htmlDoc = Nothing
Set objResults1 = Nothing
Set objResults2 = Nothing
Set objResults3 = Nothing
Set objHTTP = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What value is lastRow?

Comment: If I had to guess google is cutting you off after a certain amount of aggresive requests.  Therefore you need to be kinder and put in a pause in your program so you are not spamming requests in an almost DDoS way.  try this right before your For Loop's Next. Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:6"))  The application will pause after each loop for 6 seconds, you can vary that to see what they find acceptable.

Comment: Your initial `Set objHTTP = CreateObject` line is ***inside*** your loop, but your `= Nothing` line is ***outside***. I'm not sure (which is why this isn't an answer, just a comment) but perhaps you're creating too many Objects without flushing them out? Or, perhaps you only need to create it once by moving it before the `For I = 2...` line?

Comment: @Carter This worked and I was able to run over 100 at one time, thank you so much!

Comment: @AntonioF Glad it helped.  Would you mind me rewriting it as an answer and accepting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here turned out to be too many requests too quickly to google using the below GET request in a For loop:

```
With objHTTP
.Open "GET", URL, False
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
.send
htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText

End With
```

In order to make this code request at an acceptable pace to the server we are requesting from we add a pause in the loop.

The easiest built in way to pause in VBA is with:

```
For I = 2 To lastRow
... 'Lines omitted for clarity of purpose
...
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:6"))
Next
```

The application will then wait until that time to continue executing (an unfortunate limitation with this method is 1 second is the minimum wait time, so smaller values would need a different solution, Application.Wait and examples that could create a smaller delay outlined [Here](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/pausing-or-delaying-vba-using-wait-sleep-or-a-loop))